# jquery draggable whole entity not just text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to grab the whole cell/box around the words Frank or Joe.  Not just the text"Frank" or "Joe". I have tried li and divs to no avail. When i drag Frank, it should be rectangular shape around the word Frank with yellow background.

```
<div id='something'>
  <ul>
    <li class='draggable' id='frank'>Frank</li>
    <li class='draggable' id='Joe'>Joe</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

or trying divs:

```
<div id='somethingElse'>
  <div class='dragme' id='frank'>Frank</div>
  <div class='dragme' id='joe'>Joe</div>
</div>

$(function() {
  $( "li" ).draggable();
  $(".dragme").draggable();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/so3tckfr/3/)

Comment: **[Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/so3tckfr/6/)**?

Answer (score 0):

Its gonna be:

```
$(function(){
  $('#somethingElse').draggable()
}
```

If you want to select the wrapper div not the elements within it. But if you want just the words then just set in your CSS:

```
.draggable, .dragMe {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

and this as your function:

```
$(function() {
  $( "li" ).draggable();
  $(".dragme").draggable();
});
```